# html5 canvas, display text when user clicks on an image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have a page with an HTML5 canvas, on which several images are displayed.There are four 'description box' images and a number of other images, each one belonging to one of the description boxes.

The user is required to drag each image to its corresponding description box.

Currently it is possible to drag the images around the canvas, although I have not added the functionality to drop them to the boxes yet.

Before doing that, I want to add some 'tips and hints' for the user. The way I want to do this, is by displaying a text prompt to the user outside the canvas area each time they click on one of the 'draggable' images, or hover the cursor over a description box. The text prompt will just contain more information about whichever icon it is the user has selected/ hovered over.

I have added an HTML5 textarea on the page below the canvas, and this is where I want to display the tips and hints.

I have a couple of JS arrays, one containing all of the images that are displayed on the canvas, and another containing all of the tips. The tips will only be displayed one at a item since, obviously, the cursor can only be in one place at any given time.

So, what I want to happen, is to use an 'if' statement, so that if the user clicks on an image, then the text tip corresponding to that image will be displayed in the text box, or if the cursor hovers over a description box, then the text tip corresponding to that description box will be displayed in the text box.

I have used the kinetic.js library to add the drag and drop functionality to the images on my canvas, although I am using a copy of the library that I've saved locally, as I needed to change a couple of things with regard to its functionality. (The things I needed to change were that originally, the library cleared the canvas of anything that had been drawn to it, outside of the drag and drop function whenever an image was dropped, and just redrew the images to which the drag and drop function was being added back to it, so I lost a few other things that I was drawing to the canvas, which I didn't want to be draggable.)

I know that I will need to edit the kinetic.js library I'm using further in order to add this functionality with the hints, but I was just wondering if anyone know how I can display the hints from my array in the text area I've added to my page?

I've had a look at the 'HTML5 textarea tag' page on w3schools, but I can't see any attributes that allow you to define the text that is displayed in the text area. I also had a look at the 'event attributes' page that is linked from that page, but couldn't see any attributes there that looked like they would perform the function I wanted.

Is a textarea the best thing to use to display the text I want to display when a user selects an image or hovers over one of my description boxes? Or is there something else that would display the text (preferably outside the canvas area of the page), and allow me to change the text that is displayed dynamically?

**Edit to show HTML 31/12/2012 @ 14:40**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
  canvas{
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
    background:#F5F5F5;
  }
</style>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="kinetic.js"></script>
<script src="drawdescriptionboxes.js"></script>
<script src="drawLevelOneElements.js"></script>
<script src="startgamedrawgameelementsdrawstartbutton.js"></script>
<script>
/*Add the game elements' global variables */
var currentLevel = 1;
var totalLevels = 3;
var currentScore = 0;
var currentScorePositionX = 950;
var currentScorePositionY = 10;

/*Add code to draw images to random locations here */
    //var imageX = Math.floor(Math.random()*950);
    //var imageY = Math.floor(Math.random()*450);

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: "container",
      width: 1000,
      height: 500
    });
    var imagesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var canvas = imagesLayer.getCanvas();
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    console.log("Foo ");

/*Load the images from the HTML into the JavaScript */
function loadImages(sources, callback){
    var imagesDir = "";
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;

    //console.log("length " + sources.length);
    for (var src in sources){
        numImages++;
    }
    //console.log("Num Images " + numImages);

    var index=0;
    console.log("length " + sources.length);
    for (index=0;index < numImages ;index++){
        console.log(index);
        images[index] = new Image();
        images[index].src = sources[index];
        console.log("Adding " + sources[index]);
        callback(images[index]);
        console.log("images array length = " + images.length);
    }

    stage.add(imagesLayer); // should only be added once!!
}

/*Function to check whether the item being dragged is near its description box */
function isNearDescriptionBox(itemImage, descriptionBox){
    var ii = itemImage;
    var db = descriptionBox;
    if(ii.attrs.x > db.x - 20 && ii.attrs.x < db.x + 20 && ii.attrs.y > db.y - 20 && ii.attrs.y < db.y +20){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

/* This function draws the game elements */
function drawGameElements(){
    /* Draw a line for the 'score bar'. */
    context.moveTo(0, 25);
    context.lineTo(1000, 25);
    context.stroke();

    /* Draw current level/ total levels on the left, and current score on the right. */
    context.font = "11pt Calibri"; /* Text font & size */
    context.strokeStyle = "black"; /* Font colour */
    context.strokeText(currentLevel + "/" + totalLevels, 10, 15);
    context.strokeText(currentScore, 750, 15);
}

function initStage(images){
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: "container",
        width: 1000,
        height: 500
    });
    var descriptionLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    //var imagesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var allImages = [];
    var currentScore = 0;

    var descriptionBoxes = {
        assetsDescriptionBox: {
            x: 70,
            y: 400
        },
        liabilitiesDescriptionBox: {
            x: 300,
            y: 400
        },
        incomeDescriptionBox: {
            x: 530,
            y: 400
        },
        expenditureDescriptionBox: {
            x: 760,
            y: 400
        },
    };

    /*Code to detect whether image has been dragged to correct description box */
    for (var key in sources){
        /*Anonymous function to induce scope */
        (function(){
            var privateKey = key;
            var imageSource = sources[key];

            /*Check if image has been dragged to the correct box, and add it to that box's
                array and remove from canvas if it has */
            canvasImage.on("dragend", function(){
                var descriptionBox = descriptionBoxes[privateKey];
                if(!canvasImage.inRightPlace && isNearDescriptionBox(itemImage, descriptionBox)){
                    context.remove(canvasImage);
                    /*Will need to add a line in here to add the image to the box's array */
                }
            })

        })();
    }

}

function drawImage(imageObj) {
    //var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      // puts the image in teh middle of the canvas
      x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      draggable: true
    });

    // add cursor styling
    canvasImage.on('mouseover', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
    canvasImage.on('mouseout', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    imagesLayer.add(canvasImage);
}

/*This code loads the images to the canvas when the browser window loads */
window.onload = function(){
    var sources = {};
        /*I've removed the code from here which simply adds the images in the hidden section of the html to the 'sources' JS array */


    loadImages(sources, drawImage);
    drawGameElements();
    drawDescriptionBoxes();
};
/*Try adding an if statement to display the text corresponding to whichever icon is selected */
if(document.body.innerText){
    var message = div.innerText;
} else {
    var message = div.innerHTML.replace(/\&lt;br\&gt;/gi,"\n").replace(/(&lt;([^&gt;]+)&gt;)/gi, "");
}

/*What I want to do here is, detect where on the canvas the mouse has been clicked, then if the click is
    on a part of the canvas that is displaying an image, get the ID belonging to that image, and display 
    the corresponding tip from the tips array in tips.js on the page below the canvas.*/
function isClickOnImage(event){
    var clickX = event.clientX;
    var clickY = event.clientY;

    var imageCheckIteration = 0;
    while(imageCheckIteration < sources.length){
        if((clickX > sources[imageCheckIteration].x && clickX < sources[imageCheckIteration].x + imageWidth) &&
        (clickY > sources[imageCheckIteration].y && clickY < sources[imageCheckIteration].y + imageHeight)){
            /*This is where I need to print the variable that holds the text I want to display, but I need to display its contents
            outside the canvas, in the <p></p> tags below. */
            document.getElementById("tipsParagraph").innerHTML = tips[imageCheckIteration];
        }
    }
}

</script>


</head>
<body>

<p><textarea>This is where the text will be displayed.</textarea></p>

<section hidden>
/*The code in this hidden section simply loads a number of images into the html, giving them an 'id', a 'src' and an 'alt' tag. */



</section>
</body>
</html>
```

I've removed the code used to add the images into the hidden section in the HTML, and for adding them from there into the JS array, simply to reduce the amount of code shown.

**Edit 07/01/2013 @ 15:00**

I've edited the code to show the function "isClickOnImage(event)". When I wrote this function, I expected it to change the text in the

tags labelled "tipsParagraph" to whatever element of the 'tips' array corresponded to the image that was clicked on. But for some reason, when I click on an image on the canvas, nothing happens to the paragraph that I expect to be updated. Any idea why?

Comment: Is the actual question you are asking, one of... How do I set the content of a textarea element? `textarea.value`. Is a textarea element best used for this application? No textarea is for user input use something like a div element and set `innerHTML` or `textContent`

Comment: i think you should bring some code example, instead of writing a poem ;)

Comment: I tried using the innerHTML thing you mentioned, following the example at: http://www.davidtong.me/innerhtml-innertext-textcontent-html-and-text/ but this doesn't seem to have made a difference to what's displayed on the screen... I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly? I'll add the HTML for my page now.

Comment: So the `document.body.innerText` thing you mentioned didn't work... or at least not with the way I've used it- would this be the correct way to use it, or have I dont something wrong? Is there anything else you would suggest?

Comment: Any ideas? I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use some native implementation of KineticJS, in this case you only need it for events, just add JQuery to your project, and use the selector to change the text of the text area.

```
  //this can easily be used in your KineticJS event function.
  $("textarea").val(message);
```

I would suggest you give your text area an id and use $('#textAreaId').val('hello world'); to set your message

Comment: Apparently a text area isn't what I want to use here, as they're generally used for collecting input, rather than displaying output, which I guess makes sense. Someone else has suggested using the "DOM to add some css styled text in a div or p tag and make it appear at the right place." Is there a simple way to display the text stored in one of the elements of a JS array in a standard html p tag?

Comment: again, easy using jQuery. $('p').val(myArray[1]); if you only have one p, otherwise I suggest using '#id'. In jQuery you use $() as a selector, and in quotes you put '#' followed by the id of the element. Example you may have <p id='myParagraph'>myText</p> then use $('#myParagraph').val(myArray[1]);

Comment: you can add jquery to your page by simply pasting <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> into your <head> section

Comment: Ok, brilliant. Thanks- that sounds like it's exactly what I want to do. Quick follow up question- having never used jQuery before, I'm not sure where I would insert it? i.e. at the moment, in the <body></body> section of my page, I have <p></p> tags, inside which being where I want to display the text from my array, but I can't just put the jQuery straight inside the <p></p> tags, as it would just display the query as text when viewing my page in the browser, it wouldn't actually perform the function intended. Where should I put the jQuery?

Comment: You'd put it in the <head> <!-- jQuery goes here -_></head> section. Here is a quick tutorial:  http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: I put a <script src =...> line in the head to include the jQuery, but presumably, I need to put some where I want to actually then use it, for example, I've tried the line: `<p id = "tipsParagraph">This is where the text will be displayed. <script>$('p').val(tips[imageCheckIteration]);</script></p>` so that the jQuery should theoretically change that line of HTML to include the text from the array whenever an image is clicked... but it doesn't actually change the text when I click an image for some reason...

Comment: In terms of best practices, you want to minimize the amount of javascript you put in the <body> section (I assume the <p> is in your <body>). What you are trying to do is create a 'click' event, which does something when you click something. First of all, the javascript should be in the head section as you have at the top of this page. Second, if you want something to fire then you need the click function assigned to it. with jQuery you can do this with $('#tipsParagraph').click( function(){ do something function }); Lastly, you need $('#tipsParagraph') instead of $('p') as that is better code

Comment: if you'd like more specific help, paste your code in a jsfiddle, its free and doesn't require any signup. jsfiddle.net

Comment: I've put a JSfiddle up here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Vg3k/ but for some reason, in the result section of the page, only the text outside of the canvas is displayed, the canvas and everything on it don't appear. When I view my page in a browser, the canvas and all of the images are displayed, and it is possible to drag and drop the images around the canvas. Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Vg3k/1/ here is a slight fix. I changed the where your kinetic.js file is sourced from. So, now you'll be getting is from the net.

Comment: I'm using a local copy because I've changed one of the functions in it slightly- originally, when drawing images to the canvas using the function in the library, it would clear the canvas completely before drawing the images- but I already had a few things on the canvas which didn't need to be manipulated by the library, but needed to remain on the canvas, so I stopped the library's drawImage function from clearing the canvas first, before drawing an image to the canvas... Do you know how I could sort out my problem?

Comment: What sort of things are you drawing onto the canvas? Initially, I would say that if you want the functionality of the library, keep the drawImage function. Instead, use the library to create the things you are drawing. This seems to be the only option. Otherwise, maybe you could load the library first, drawing the images, and then use your own functions to draw on the canvas. I don't know how to help you exactly because you haven't clearly explained the problem. I think I resolved your original question, maybe create a new question and you'll get more input from other people.

Comment: I think the problem with the library clearing things was when dragging and dropping images around the canvas- as soon as the 'mousedown' was detected on an image, everything that had been drawn to the canvas but not by the library was cleared- so I just removed that clear function from the mousedown event. That is literally the only thing I have changed in the library compared to using the one available online

Comment: I understand thats the function that you removed, but what are you getting, vs what do you want to happen? Expected output vs Actual output. If it's to keep the library drawings and your custom drawings, then you will have to extend the library framework to account for that... best case. otherwise you'll have to redraw your items each time as they will be cleared. Have you tried to draw all your items onto a custom layer?

Comment: No- I haven't used any layers, I've just drawn straight to the canvas. Should I be using a layer?

Comment: I've just noticed- I'm getting a 'Reference error' where I've inserted the line `isClickOnImage(event);` in the local copy of Kinetic.js, which says that 'event' is not defined- do I need to refer to this with the full filepath or something?

Comment: I'm now getting the messages "Reference error: div is not defined" and "Reference error: $ is not defined" on the line `<p id = "tipsParagraph">This is where the text will be displayed. <script>$('p').val(tips[imageCheckIteration]);</script></p>` Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Well, now that you're using the <p> instead of <textarea> you should use .text() instead of .val(). http://api.jquery.com/text/  also, updated your code to include an example. http://jsfiddle.net/4Vg3k/4/

Comment: Brilliant- that's got rid of the one reference error- so thanks very much for that! Do you know how I can sort out the other one? The error is: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined " on the line `<p id = "tipsParagraph">This is where the text will be displayed. <script>$('p').text(tips[imageCheckIteration]);</script></p>` If I expand the error message, it says that it is an anonymous function, any idea why that is, and what I need to do to put it right?

Comment: I noticed in the example in the link you provided that they use double quotes rather than single quotes for the the `<script>$("p").text... ` but changing them doesn't seem to make a difference for me- I still get the "uncaught reference error" saying that "$ is not defined". I would have thought that the '$' character would have a function defined by the language, and that I wouldn't need to define it? Unless I'm completely missing the boat here, and the problem is something else entirely?

Comment: Once again, dont use $('p') the 'p' is killing your code. That is not specific enough as you may have more than one p. You NEED to use the '#id_of_your_p_tag' instead, otherwise you'll just get errors. You'll notice the jsfiddle does not have that error because it is more specific.

Comment: The only reason that $ would be undefined would be that jQuery is not linked in your code. If it somehow is and is still not working, try using jQuery() instead of $(), as $ is short for jQuery in the jQuery library.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the 'p' to the ID of the 'p', and also tried using jQuery() instead of $(), but I still had the same result- to check if I'm linking jQuery correctly- I have the line `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` at the top of my file, with all the other JS files I'm including- is this the correct way to link jQuery to my code?

Comment: post all of your code in a new jsfiddle so I can see exactly what's going on, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Ok, great. The new jsfiddle is at: http://jsfiddle.net/wQkSd/   Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Yeah, your fiddle isn't showing that error, maybe the code you're running is at fault.

Comment: I've just noticed that there's also an error that says: "GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" would that mean there's something wrong with the way I've referenced the library?

Comment: Download the file from jquery.com and put it in a folder and link it that way.

Comment: Excellent- cheers! That seems to have sorted it- at least there is now one tip being displayed in the paragraph below the canvas, although for some reason, it's the first element in the 'tips' array that's being displayed, and it is displayed constantly, i.e. it's there straight away when the page loads (before clicking on an image), and clicking on another image doesn't change it to the relevant tip. I guess this means that there's something wrong with the logic in my code? Any pointers as to what it could be?